# What does "No suitable Python runtime found" mean?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I ran a Python program by typing this: `python mitmf.py --help` and I got this error:

> No suitable Python runtime found
> Pass --list (-0) to see all detected environments on your machine
> or set environment variable PYLAUNCHER_ALLOW_INSTALL to use winget
> or open the Microsoft Store to the requested version.

What does this error mean?

Comment: Are you able to run the `python` command by itself? What is the output of `python --version`?

Comment: this is the output `Python 3.12.0`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you ran the python mitmf.py on the Windows Command Prompt or something like that. In that case, you should use python3 mitmf.py instead of without the 3. Type python3 mitmf.py --help on the command prompt.

If that doesn't work, ensure that python is installed. You can check if it installed by python3 --version or python --version. If it isn't installed, use your browser or something to install it.

The error message also mentions using winget or the Microsoft Store, so check that out too. In the meantime, try identifying what PYLAUNCHER_ALLOW_INSTALL  is. It's an environment variable, so ensure it's set correctly to allow for python, or specify the correct version of python.

Comment: I got this `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?` when ran it use `python3 mitmf.py --help`